# What is an appropriate hebrew translation of 'ought to be put into geniza'?

Tags: words, hebrew, genizah-storage

I have some texts that are not religious (like dictionary) but contain The Name. And because it's not obvious that one should not recycle them, but rather put to geniza, I want to mark them somehow.
So, is there some traditional phrase equivalent to 'put this to geniza' or 'contains The Names' in Hebrew?
How do israelis inform about that in, let's say, religious newspapers?

Comment: "Shaimos" but this seems to be off-topic.

Comment: Not sure if this is off-topic, actually. There appears to be some "practical" / halachic use to this question. Even the question about how to phrae it in a Hebrew paper has "use".

Comment: chschtsch, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! This question is about implementation of Judaism and is therefore 100% on-topic. I hope you'll look around and find other content in our archives that you'll be happy we preserved for you, perhaps starting with some of our dozens of [tag:shemos-sacred-names] questions.

Comment: האם הדבר ״צריך גניזה״? Genizah is also the gerund ("ing") form of the verb Lignoz.

Comment: .....טעון גניזה

Comment: @mevaqesh what does the word טעון mean, in this context?

Comment: @DanF "needs" this is a common expression. e.g. [link](http://gniza.org.il/he/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%A2-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99/%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%96%D7%94/)

Comment: Thank you for the correction, @mevaqesh. I knew צריך didn't sound right; but, couldn't think of the word I'd heard used many times before.

Comment: @mevaqesh I echo Lee ^^^; I was going to ask the same Q about צריך. Interesting article. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The used term in newspapers is "טעון גניזה"

Comment: Thanks for this information.  Have you seen this directly?  (Where?)  Or did you learn this some other way?  If you could [edit] in how you know, that would improve this answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The Hebrew term you're looking for is "שֵׁמוֹת" - [*shaimos*](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-mitzvos-shaimos.htm) or *shemot* (or some other transliteration along these lines). The word literally means "names" and, in this context, refers specifically to items that contain Holy Names of God (as you've specified) or are otherwise not to be discarded due to their holiness.

Here's an example of this term being used to warn people of holy content. The [April 25-26, 2014 edition](http://wp.yise.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/shabshorts-kedoshim.pdf) of the [Young Israel Shomrai Emunah](http://yise.org) "Shabbos Shorts" weekly newsletter contains the notice:

> **Shaimos Alert** - [YU Pesach To-Go 5774](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/817666/Editor_To-Go/Benjamin_and_Rose_Berger_Pesach_To-Go_5774#) contains Shaimos on page 13 (and
>   possibly other pages)

<sup>(Link added by me)</sup>

Comment: I am concerned about universal use of the term. For non-Hebrew speaker it sure is obvious what 'Shemot' (especially styled as 'Shaimos') means. But in Hebrew there are many other uses of this word. That's why i mentioned israelites.

Comment: @chschtsch do you mean Israelis, meaning people who speak Modern Hebrew?

Comment: Yes, I mean people who live in Israel.

Comment: I wonder if the usage of "shaimis" derives from Hebrew or Yiddish...

Comment: @DoubleAA What would the Yiddish etymology be?

Answer (score 6):

The sentence I usually see used on printed material is:

"נא לשמור על קדושת הגליון"

=Please preserve the holiness of [this printed] sheet.

I see this on material like the brochures about the weekly Torah reading which different organizations publish and distribute in synagogues.

Answer (score 1):

I think that religious people are familiar with the phrasing לגניזה. That seems to cover both the content that something contains "religious materials" as well as the action itself, that you wish them buried.

BTW, there are numerous items that people assume are "shaimos" that really are not. I'll edit in a link to an article about this, later. Thus, I would caution that prior to declaring such items, make sure that this is really necessary for the items you want to "dispose". *Genizah* is costly - if not monetarily, it is labor and time-consuming to an extent.